# Why `\n` doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, string

In my Android application I have

```
<string name="key1">Hello \n world </string>
```

and its print out

Hello
World

but when I put it on asset and try to read string from there `\n` doesn't work.

Here is my asset api.xml

```
  <string name="key1" lang_iso="en">Hello \n world</string>
```

I use XML parser and put it on HashMap for getting it.

```
private boolean parseData(String response){
        HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>> mainHashMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
        XmlMGParser config = new XmlMGParser(response);
        for(XmlMGParser element:config.children("string")){
            String name = element.string("name");
            String lang = element.string("lang_iso");
            if (!mainHashMap.containsKey(lang)){
                mainHashMap.put(lang,new HashMap<String, String>());
            }
            HashMap<String,String> hashMap = mainHashMap.get(lang);
            hashMap.put(name, element.content());
        }
        return true;
    }
```

What is the problem it's going to be there? Or it's cause because of XMLMGParser?

XMLMGParser.java

```
public class XmlMGParser {

    private String name;
    private String content;
    private Map<String,String> nameAttributes = new HashMap<String,String>();
    private Map<String,ArrayList<XmlMGParser>> nameChildren = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<XmlMGParser>>();

    public XmlMGParser(InputStream inputStream, String rootName) {
        this(rootElement(inputStream,rootName));
    }

    public XmlMGParser(String filename, String rootName) {
        this(fileInputStream(filename),rootName);
    }

    public XmlMGParser(String xml) {
        this(rootElement(xml));
    }

    private XmlMGParser(Element element) {
        this.name = element.getNodeName();
        this.content = element.getTextContent();
        NamedNodeMap namedNodeMap = element.getAttributes();
        int n = namedNodeMap.getLength();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            Node node = namedNodeMap.item(i);
            String name = node.getNodeName();
            addAttribute(name,node.getNodeValue());
        }
        NodeList nodes = element.getChildNodes();
        n = nodes.getLength();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            Node node = nodes.item(i);
            int type = node.getNodeType();
            if(type==Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                XmlMGParser child = new XmlMGParser((Element)node);
                addChild(node.getNodeName(),child);
            }

        }
    }

    public void addAttribute(String name, String value) {
        nameAttributes.put(name,value);
    }

    private void addChild(String name, XmlMGParser child) {
        ArrayList<XmlMGParser> children = nameChildren.get(name);
        if(children==null) {
            children = new ArrayList<XmlMGParser>();
            nameChildren.put(name,children);
        }
        children.add(child);
    }

    public String name() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String content() {
        return content;
    }

    public void addChild(XmlMGParser xml) {
        addChild(xml.name(),xml);
    }

    public void addChildren(XmlMGParser... xmls) {
        for(XmlMGParser xml:xmls) addChild(xml.name(),xml);
    }

    public XmlMGParser child(String name) {
        XmlMGParser child = optChild(name);
        if(child==null) throw new RuntimeException("Could not find child node: "+name);
        return child;
    }

    public XmlMGParser optChild(String name) {
        ArrayList<XmlMGParser> children = children(name);
        int n = children.size();
        if(n>1) throw new RuntimeException("Could not find individual child node: "+name);
        return n==0 ? null : children.get(0);
    }

    public boolean option(String name) {
        return optChild(name)!=null;
    }

    public ArrayList<XmlMGParser> children(String name) {
        ArrayList<XmlMGParser> children = nameChildren.get(name);
        return children==null ? new ArrayList<XmlMGParser>() : children;
    }

    public String string(String name) {
        String value = optString(name);
        if(value==null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Could not find attribute: "+name+", in node: "+this.name);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public String optString(String name) {
        return nameAttributes.get(name);
    }

    public int integer(String name) {
        return Integer.parseInt(string(name));
    }

    public Integer optInteger(String name) {
        String string = optString(name);
        return string==null ? null : integer(name);
    }

    public double doubleValue(String name) {
        return Double.parseDouble(optString(name));
    }

    public Double optDouble(String name) {
        String string = optString(name);
        return string==null ? null : doubleValue(name);
    }

    private static Element rootElement(InputStream inputStream, String rootName) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(inputStream);
            Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
            if(!rootElement.getNodeName().equals(rootName))
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not find root node: "+rootName);
            return rootElement;
        }
        catch(IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
        catch(ParserConfigurationException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
        catch(SAXException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
        finally {
            if(inputStream!=null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                catch(Exception exception) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(exception);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static Element rootElement(String xml){

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        Document dom=null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
            InputSource source = new InputSource(reader);
            dom = builder.parse(source);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        } catch (SAXException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
         Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
        return root;
    }

    private static FileInputStream fileInputStream(String filename) {
        try {
            return new FileInputStream(filename);
        }
        catch(IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings uses HTML format so instead of `/n`, you should use `<BR>`.

```
<string name="key1">Hello <BR> world </string>
```

Comment: it doesn't respond. I mean nothing happened I also use setText(Html.fromHtml(...))

Comment: Ah... then you need to hard code it in that method's parameter only. Otherwise it is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you using the string as HTML, you can use <br /> for a line break

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
 <string name="title">Hello&lt;br /&gt;world!</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<string name="key1">"Hello \n world "</string>
```

You need to put "" around your string to apply \n.